# Why do these identical weapon coils give different results?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I've noticed something weird when modifying my weapons.

If a weapon has equipped, for example, a `+6% damage +6% tear` coil and I want to replace it with an identical one, the weapon's stats don't give me the same result.

I'm wondering if weapon modifiers bugged or if coils' percentages aren't exact numbers, but approximated values? Because I really don't understand how this actually works.

I'm not the only one how have noticed [something weird](https://www.reddit.com/r/horizon/comments/5x94aj/weapon_coils_are_weird_bug_psa/), there should be some math messed up somewhere.

Here's an example.

The Blast Sling have a `+6% damage +6% handling` coil equipped, but if I try to replace it with a theoretically identical `+6% handling +6% damage` coil this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add in a screenshot of what you are doing? That way we can see the values being changed? Might bring something to light faster.

Comment: @Dupree3 screenshot added.

Comment: that is super odd. I just played through this and never encountered a coil that did that. Anything that had the same stats, ended up the same. Is it like that only with the one coil?

Comment: @Dupree3 it happens very often, I get different results with several similar coils.

Comment: Internally the stats may be floats (e.g. 6.01 vs 6.49) and are rounded for display.  But in the full calculation for the weapon, the fraction causes the total to round differently.

Comment: @BenJackson I agree, but it's a bit annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been observed a handful of times by users and the general consensus is that there are hidden decimals that you can't see but will affect the outcome of applying the mods. From [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/horizon/comments/5yyusy/some_of_my_findings_regarding_very_rare_mods/):

> Two mods with the same x% stat don't necessarily increase by the same amount. I think there's some kind of decimal system in place.

And [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/horizon/comments/5xupzj/3_6_damage_mods_all_show_different_amounts_added/):

> I'm fairly certain that there is decimals that you don't see.
>
> Like you said I've had multiple say 10% ones. Normally they'd add like 5 but sometimes the bar will move up and it be 6 or 4.
>
> The damage/modifiers increase is based on how full those little slashes are.

And from [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168644-horizon-zero-dawn/75324012):

> The 20% mod changing to 19% could be a rounding difference. I've always known that mods have decimal numbers that you can't see. 2 identical looking mods can occasionally give different stat bonuses, and it's because of the decimal.

In the last thread, users were discussing an update that was released after the time this question was posted that changed a lot of their mod values. It may be that the invisible decimal was a bug and these values have been changed to more accurately represent the boosts they grant, but unless you still have the mods from the question, it will be hard to prove, though I suspect that this was just another one of these cases.

Comment: I haven't tried the game yet after the big update, I hope this was fixed.